# How to get the amount of days between two datetime objects in flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I want to find the difference in days between two different datetimes in flutter.

in other words, i want to subtract two dates and get the difference between them
I found a way to do this in c# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754316/get-the-number-of-days-between-two-different-datetime-objects). But unfortunately this doesn't apply for flutter.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `difference` method of `DateTime` class to get the duration between two dates in dart.

```
 DateTime date1 = new DateTime.now();
 DateTime date2 = DateTime(2021, 1, 1);
 print(date1.difference(date2).inDays); // Prints 356 days
```

Comment: Be aware that unless you use UTC `DateTime` objects, your calculation might not be what you expect if a DST change occurs during that timespan.

Answer (score 0):

// get current date & time

```
  DateTime startDate = DateTime.now();
        String currentTime = formatISOTime(startDate);
```

//convert date to String

```
String formatISOTime(DateTime date) {
    var duration = date.timeZoneOffset;
    if (duration.isNegative)
      return (date.toIso8601String() +
          "-${duration.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(duration.inMinutes - (duration.inHours * 60)).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}");
    else
      return (date.toIso8601String() +
          "+${duration.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(duration.inMinutes - (duration.inHours * 60)).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}");
  }
```

//calculate time difference

```
String? timediffference = calculateTimeDifferenceBetween(
                              givenDate ?? '',
                              currentTime) ??
                          '',

 static String? calculateTimeDifferenceBetween(
      String? givenDate, String? currentTime) {
    if (givenDate == null ||
        givenDate.isEmpty ||
        currentTime == null ||
        currentTime.isEmpty) {
      return "";
    } else {
      String gDate = givenDate.replaceAll('T', ' ');

      String curTime = currentTime.replaceAll('T', ' ');

      DateTime startParseDate =
          new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(curTime);
      DateTime endParseDate =
          new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(gDate);

      Duration diff = startParseDate.difference(endParseDate);

      if (diff.inDays >= 1) {
        return '${diff.inDays} day ago';
      } else if (diff.inDays >= 30) {
        return '${diff.inDays % 30} months ago';
      } else if (diff.inDays >= 365) {
        return '${diff.inDays % 365} years ago';
      } else if (diff.inHours >= 1) {
        return '${diff.inHours} hours ago';
      } else if (diff.inHours < 1) {
        if (diff.inMinutes >= 1) {
          return '${diff.inMinutes} minutes ago';
        } else if (diff.inMinutes < 1) {
          return  'just now ';
        } else {
          return 'just now ';
        }
      } else {
        return 'just now ';
      }
    }
  }
```